# SlideToggle Not Animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have two container divs containing boxes four to a row.

On click of a button I want the second div to slide up and hide or down and show.

However, when I click it now it only appears or disappears and doesn't animate the slide transition. Research shows that usually this is an issue of absolute positioning, but none of the elements are absolutely positioned.

Also if I apply the onclick listener to the first div it works fine. I recreated the issue in a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6z8ft5g4/3/):

```js
$('.more').click(function() {

  $('#group2').slideToggle(400);

})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-container {
  clear: both;
}

.group-containers a {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 23.5%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.group-containers a:not(:nth-child(4n)) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.boxes {
  background-color: blue !important;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.boxes:not(:nth-child(4n)) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.boxesTwo {
  background-color: red !important;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.boxesTwo:not(:nth-child(4n)) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.labels {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 25%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.overflow-group {
  display: none;
}

.more {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section id="content-container">
    <section class="group-sections">
      <div class="group-containers" id="group1" style="display: block;">
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="group-containers overflow-group" id="group2" style="display: block;">
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="more">See more</div>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within your `float` on `.group-containers a`. Here's an example with `display: inline-block` instead.

```js
$('.more').click(function() {

  $('#group2').slideToggle(400);

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-container {
  clear: both;
}

.group-containers a {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 22%;
  /*float: left;*/
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.group-containers a:not(:nth-child(4n)) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.boxes {
  background-color: blue !important;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.boxes:not(:nth-child(4n)) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.boxesTwo {
  background-color: red !important;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.boxesTwo:not(:nth-child(4n)) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.labels {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 25%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.overflow-group {
  display: none;
}

.more {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section id="content-container">
    <section class="group-sections">
      <div class="group-containers" id="group1" style="display: block;">
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="group-containers overflow-group" id="group2" style="display: block;">
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="more">See more</div>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow I spent a few days trying to understand what was wrong. Can you explain why exactly float doesn't work with SlideToggle() here, but display does, and why it seemed to work on the first div? I would like to avoid this in the future.

Comment: Float changes the stacking order and structure of the layout. It can probably be cleared as well, if you insist on staying with floats.

Answer (score -1):

It does not seem to be a problem. It can be due to jsfiddle.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.more').click(function(){

  $('#group2').slideToggle(400);
 
})
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<style>

html, body{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
.container{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
#content-container{
 clear:both;
}

.group-containers a{
 background-color:blue;
 height: 200px;
 width:23.5%;
 float:left;
 margin-top:2%;
 
}
.group-containers a:not(:nth-child(4n)){
 margin-right:2%;
}
.boxes{
 background-color:blue !important;
 height: 200px;
 width:100%;
 float:left;
}
.boxes:not(:nth-child(4n)){
 margin-right:2%;
}
.boxesTwo{
 background-color:red !important;
 height: 200px;
 width:100%;
 float:left;
}
.boxesTwo:not(:nth-child(4n)){
 margin-right:2%;
}
.labels{
 background-color:blue;
 height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 margin-top:25%;
 padding-top:5%;
 margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}
.overflow-group{
 display:none;
}
.more{
 height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:2%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <section id="content-container">
    <section class="group-sections">
     <div class="group-containers" id="group1" style="display: block;">
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxes lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="group-containers overflow-group" id="group2" style="display: block;">
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div class="boxesTwo lazy" style="background: url() no-repeat center">
            <div class="labels">label</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
 
    <div class="more">See more</div>
  </section>
 </section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The red boxes at the bottom should slide up and down. Instead, they just appear and disappear. If you change the duration of Slidetoggle() the lack of transition may be clearer.